# What is required in the hosting environment for WordPress to process an image into multiple sizes?

Tags: images, hosting

I'm looking for source documentation on what hosting environment prerequisites there are for the hosting environment so that WordPress can process images into multiple sizes.

All the libraries necessary to process images in the way WordPress does are not included in the PHP core of WordPress itself. I'm looking for a list of what additional libraries on which WordPress relies.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean exactly? WordPress, by default, creates multiple sizes for uploaded images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress uses Imagemagick for image processing if it's available and falls back to php-gd if it's available. If neither are available, then no image processing is done.

Have a browse through the source code:

- [class-wp-image-editor-gd.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/class-wp-image-editor-gd.php)
- [class-wp-image-editor-imagick.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/class-wp-image-editor-imagick.php)
- [class-wp-image-editor.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/class-wp-image-editor.php)

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, only GD is available by default on any environment that can run PHP. ImageMagick needs to be installed.